# reactjs JWT token bearer and redirect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oauth, promise

I have router configured to make redirect to '/' route.:

```
let PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={PrivateRender(Component)} />
);

let PrivateRender = (Component: any) => {
    return (props: any) => {
        return securityApi.isAuthenticated().then(x =>
            x ? (<Component {...props} />)
            : (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />)
        )
    }
};

export const routes = <Layout>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path='/lobby' component={Lobby} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path='/lobby/blackjack' component={Blackjack} />
</Layout>;
```

It works sure incorrect because pf promise method:
securityApi.isAuthenticated()

Here is this method:

```
 isAuthenticated() {
        return axios.get('/api/token/ping')
            .then((response) => {
                return true;
            })
            .catch(reason => {
                return axios.post("/api/token/refresh", { refreshToken: window.sessionStorage.getItem("refresh_token") })

                    .then(() => {
                        return true;
                        // todo: update storages with new jws and refresh_token values
                    })
                    .catch((reason) => {
                        return false;
                    });
            });
    }
```

So, how to resolve this situation?